# Numpy or Pandas function for "x-value-window" means or other stats?

Tags: numpy, pandas

Let's say I have x-y data samples sorted by x-value. I'm going to use Pandas as example, but I would be perfectly happy with a Numpy/Scipy-only solution, of course.

```
In [24]: pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10)

In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2), columns=['x', 'y'])

In [26]: df = df.sort('x')

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
       x         y
13 -3.403818  0.717744
49 -2.688876  1.936267
74 -2.388332 -0.121599
52 -2.185848  0.617896
90 -2.155343 -1.132673
..       ...       ...
65  1.736506 -0.170502
0   1.770901  0.520490
60  1.878376  0.206113
63  2.263602  1.112115
33  2.384195 -1.877502

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Now, I want to kind of "window" it or "discretize" it and get statistics on each window. But I don't want to do the Pandas [moving-window functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments) because they define windows by rows. I want to define windows by a span of x-values, thus "x-value-window". Specifically, let's define each x-value-window with 2 parameters:

1. center x-value of each window

   - in this example, let's say I want x = 0.0 + 0.4 * k for all positive or negative k
   - thus -3.2, -2.8, -2.4, ..., 1.6, 2.0, 2.4
2. width of each window

   - in this example, let's say I want W = 0.5
   - thus, the example windows will be [-3.2-0.25, -3.2+0.25], [-2.8-0.25, -2.8+0.25], ..., [2.4-0.25, 2.4+0.25]
   - note that the windows overlap, which is intended

Having thus defined the windows, I would like to ask if there's a function that will produce the following data frame (or numpy array):

```
  x         y
-3.2    mean of y-values in x-value-window centered at -3.2
-2.8    mean of y-values in x-value-window centered at -2.8
-2.4    mean of y-values in x-value-window centered at -2.4
 ...       ...
 1.6    mean of y-values in x-value-window centered at  1.6
 2.0    mean of y-values in x-value-window centered at  2.0
 2.4    mean of y-values in x-value-window centered at  2.4
```

Is there anything that will do this for me? Or do I have to totally roll my own (and probably in a very slow python loop instead of fast numpy or pandas code)?

**Extra 1:** It would be even better if there's support for weighted windows (such as supported by Pandas's [rolling_window function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_window.html)) but of course the weights in this case would not be based on how far the sample's row is from the center row of the window, but rather, how far the sample's x-value is from the center of the x-value-window.

**Extra 2:** It would be nice if there's support for statistics other than mean on the x-value-windows, e.g. (a) variance of the y-values in each x-value-window or (b) count of the number of samples falling within each x-value-window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first create a range of x values centered at zero.  This range is wide enough so that then min value minus the width and the max value plus the width will capture all x values.

I then iterate through this range of x values which have `k` as the step size.  At each point, I use `loc` to capture `y` values located at the selected `x` value plus and minus the width. The mean of these selected values are then calculated.  These values are used to create the `result` dataframe.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

k = .4
w = .5
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2), columns=['x', 'y'])

x_range = np.arange(math.floor((df.x.min() + w) / k) * k, 
                    k * (math.ceil((df.x.max() - w) / k) + 1), k)

result = pd.DataFrame((df.loc[df.x.between(x - w, x + w), 'y'].mean() for x in x_range), 
                      index=x_range, columns=['y_mean'])
result.index.name = 'centered_x'
>>> result
                 y_mean
centered_x             
-2.400000e+00  0.653619
-2.000000e+00  0.733606
-1.600000e+00  0.576594
-1.200000e+00  0.150462
-8.000000e-01  0.065884
-4.000000e-01  0.022925
-8.881784e-16  0.211693
 4.000000e-01  0.057527
 8.000000e-01 -0.141970
 1.200000e+00  0.233695
 1.600000e+00  0.203570
 2.000000e+00  0.306409
 2.400000e+00  0.576789
```

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer! This seems closer to "roll my own" than "supported functionality" though.

Comment: This is not really the answer I was looking for (I can roll my own without help in writing the code), but I gave credit since you're the only person who took the time to write an answer.